# Can you recover IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have accidentally delete iam role for the amazon sage maker studio, now i can't open it? Can i make another role and assign to it or can it be recovered?

I can't open sagemaker studio now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the ExecutionRole what was set for a specific user profile. You can certainly create a new Role and assign this new Role as a new execution role for any Studio user. The only caveat is that the user profile cannot have any running Studio application.

To change the execution role, go to the SageMaker Studio dashboard on AWS Management Console and click on one of your user profile. If you can see any running application under the user profile, first please delete all of them (including the Jupyter server one). After that you can click on the Edit user button on the top and change the execution role.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I haven't close the associated application that was causing the issue.